# BlockReentrancy in ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, events, collections, observablecollection

Could someone please be kind enough to explain to me what the purpose of the `BlockReentrancy` Method is in the `ObservableCollection<T>` ?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654919.aspx) shows the following as an example:

```
//The typical usage is to wrap an OnCollectionChanged call within a using scope, as in the following example:

using (BlockReentrancy())
{
    // OnCollectionChanged call
}
```

But this doesn't seem to clarify for me what the purpose is. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: Pronounce it `BlockReëntrancy`

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, it worth mentioning that `using (BlockReentrancy()) {}` is also required in multi-threaded use case when collection is being updated so frequently that it interferes with the `OnCollectionChanged` processing. This can potentially happen with just a single XAML binding and without any additional explicit subscribers in the custom code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and so it has a `CollectionChanged` event.  If there is a subscriber to this event, they could **further modify** the collection while the collection is already in the process of notification.  Since the `CollectionChanged` event keeps track of exactly what changed, this interaction can get very messy.

As a result, the `ObservableCollection` allows, as a special case, a single subscriber of the `CollectionChanged` event to modify the collection from its handler.  But it **disallows** modifying the collection from the `CollectionChanged` handler **if there are two or more subscribers** to the `CollectionChanged` event.

The pair of methods `BlockReentrancy` and `CheckReentancy` are used to implement this logic.  The `BlockReentrancy` is used at the start of the `OnCollectionChanged` method and `CheckReentancy` is used in all methods that modify the collection.

Comment: Very interesting, that the MSDN documentation fails to mention this little fact, that CheckReentrancy will prevent reentrancy only when there are more than one handlers attached to the CollectionChanged event.

Comment: “it disallows modifying the collection from the CollectionChanged handler if there are two or more subscribers to the CollectionChanged event.” 
What if there is only one subscriber but there are two worker threads modifying the collection? In that case, should I use anther lock to lock the operations like Insert and Remove and also lock the OnCollectionChanged handler?

Answer (score 13):

This is implementation of `BlockReentrancy()`

```
protected IDisposable BlockReentrancy()
{
   this._monitor.Enter();
   return this._monitor;
}
```

There is another method `CheckReentrancy()`

```
protected void CheckReentrancy()
{
    if ((this._monitor.Busy && (this.CollectionChanged != null)) && (this.CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList().Length > 1))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ObservableCollectionReentrancyNotAllowed"));
    }
}
```

Such methods as `ClearItems`, `InsertItem`, `MoveItem`, `RemoveItem`, `SetItem` check `CheckReentrancy()` before modifying collection.

So the code below guarantees that collection will not be changed inside of `using`, but only if there is more than one handler subscribed to `CollectionChanged` event.

```
using BlockReentrancy())
{
    CollectionChanged(this, e);
}
```

This example demonstrates effect of `BlockReentrancy()`

```
private static void Main()
{
    collection.CollectionChanged += CollectionCollectionChanged1;
    collection.CollectionChanged += CollectionCollectionChanged2;
    collection.Add(1);
}

private static void CollectionCollectionChanged1(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    collection.Add(2); // this line will throw exception
}

private static void CollectionCollectionChanged2(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Your demonstration code will throw a `StackOverflowException` not an `InvalidOperationException`.  In this case reentrancy is not being checked.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Reentrancy is when a method does something directly or indirectly that causes that method to be invoked again, possibly recursively. In this case, the using block should be used inside the OnCollectionChanged delegate if you want to prevent the changing of the collection from within the handler; attempts to change it will throw an exception. If you didn't use it, then any attempts to modify the collection would cause OnCollectionChanged to be called again.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the [code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ObjectModel/src/System/Collections/ObjectModel/ObservableCollection.cs) behind BlockReentrancy. CheckReentrancy is called at the start of each collection modifier method in the implementation of ObservableCollection.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Disallow reentrant attempts to change this collection. E.g. an event handler
    /// of the CollectionChanged event is not allowed to make changes to this collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// typical usage is to wrap e.g. a OnCollectionChanged call with a using() scope:
    /// <code>
    ///         using (BlockReentrancy())
    ///         {
    ///             CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, item, index));
    ///         }
    /// </code>
    /// </remarks>
    protected IDisposable BlockReentrancy()
    {
        _blockReentrancyCount++;
        return EnsureMonitorInitialized();
    }

    /// <summary> Check and assert for reentrant attempts to change this collection. </summary>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> raised when changing the collection
    /// while another collection change is still being notified to other listeners </exception>
    protected void CheckReentrancy()
    {
        if (_blockReentrancyCount > 0)
        {
            // we can allow changes if there's only one listener - the problem
            // only arises if reentrant changes make the original event args
            // invalid for later listeners.  This keeps existing code working
            // (e.g. Selector.SelectedItems).
            if (CollectionChanged?.GetInvocationList().Length > 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.ObservableCollectionReentrancyNotAllowed);
        }
    }

    private SimpleMonitor EnsureMonitorInitialized()
    {
        return _monitor ?? (_monitor = new SimpleMonitor(this));
    }
```

(Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and Contributors)